# can't set value of undefined after submit action

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a problem when i press the submit button in a form.

this is my script

```
var x=[];
var y;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':button').click(function() {
    get(this.name);
    z=x.toString();
    document.querySelector('[name="datated"]').value=z;
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('input').prop('disabled',false);
    if ($('.active').length >= 6) {
        $('input:not(.active)').prop('disabled',true);
    }
  })
  function get(name){
    y=document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
    x.push(y);
  }
```

and this is my form

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" value="" name="datated">
  <input type="submit"></input>
  <input type="button" name="1" class="orange" value="1"></input>
  <input type="button" name="2" class="orange" value="2"></input>
  <input type="button" name="3" class="orange" value="3"></input>
</form>
```

when I press the button, the value of this go inside z variable. And then when I press the submit button, I expect that this value go to the php file but the console gave me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

But this is set after I click the button with the value.

Why it gives me this error?

Comment: Quick comment, your doc ready call isn't closed.  I'm assuming you cut and pasted the first part only?

Comment: Hmm, I put up a fiddle of this code (closing the doc ready :) ) and I dont get a console error when I submit the form.  Do you have any form validation being applied later in your code?

Comment: why not try giving an id to the hidden element and then use document.getElementByid()??

Comment: I don't understand the problem after running your code(and ending the doc ready) as said above i ran it and it worked perfectly echoing out all the button clicks i did before submitting?

`session_start();

$z = $_POST['datated'];
echo $z;`
put that in your test.php and try it yourself :)

Comment: @Parody, you can post code in comments by surrounding the code with back-ticks.

Comment: @sparky ahh!! i did not know ty

Comment: Wolffer yes a copy this first part.

Comment: Wolffer,No it isn't.I don't applied a form validator

Comment: Ok i stand.The form hate me xD It give me this error at line 44= y=document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
this is the problem for me.I don't want to change this because it work when i click to the button.It cause this error after i click the SUBMIT button.

Comment: can you give me the fiddle please?I will analyze it...

Comment: Vivin i use name because in PHP $_POST[''] support only the name of input and not the ID.In that case i used name because for me simplify the code.

Comment: I could be wrong here. But I don't think you can use a number as the first character of the NAME value. Same goes for an ID. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: jmiraglia thanks for reply.I don't remember this but,some times ago a do i script and the value of the name begin with a NUMBER.I will search for it and tell you about this.Nice tip

Comment: unexpeted end of input :O

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JoySscript/qcu95cdf/10/

Comment: I'm wrong,it work.But still don't work for me...

Comment: Fixed it.The error was in the submit button.It was type="button" and not type="submit".Thanks to all